# TV live streaming (.m8u3 file) plays in browser, but not in Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm developing a live streaming tv app using Swift but my channel file URL doesn't play.

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = URL(string: "http://biwsat.com:8080/get.php?username=eYIvPmJeT2&password=3331jALAKY&type=m3u&output=ts"){
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let controller=AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player=player
        controller.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        self.addChildViewController(controller)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

If I use this link: http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/102w0bsn0ge83qfv7za/102/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8 my player plays.

What should I do?

Comment: Your video file is probably in a format that is not supported by the AVPlayer, I suggest you find the documentation to see what formats are supported.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason AVPlayer doesn't accept files passed from a php Get function. It needs a straight link with .m3u8 extention. You have two choices:

**1.** Find a way to present the link so it ends in .m3u8

**2.** If you have access to editing the GET method and the server, check out [Sommer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41080374/2551645)

**3.** If you don't have access to the Server, a huge workaround that worked for me is downloading the file provided from the link and then using an implementation of a HTTP server(e.g. [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) - is lightweight and still supported) to broadcast the file and access it as a URL in the AVPlayer. Apple doesn't allow playing local m3u/m3u8 files, so you must use HTTP Live Streaming (HLS), which basically means that the file must be stored on a server.

Example can be provided if needed.