# iOS 10 AVPlayer will not stream video from URL with no extension and with video/mp4 as content type

Tags: ios, video, mime-types, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Currently, we are using a standard `AVPlayer` via `AVPlayerViewController` to play video. We are streaming video from a url in the format https://ourdomain/media/mediaid?jwt=authTokenHere. The url, as you can see, has no extension; however the headers are being set on the payload to indicate that the response is a video.

[image: HTTP Reponse Headers]

Though the links results in the video playing fine in desktop Safari and Chrome, it will not play via iOS's `AVPlayer` in our application. Is there some particular format that `AVPlayer` expects?

Comment: I believe media played in AVPlayer *must* have a file extension, I bumped into this once with files I was playing locally that had no extension. Added `.mp4` and voila.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright - ended up discovering the answer to this is multifaceted. Here's what I needed to do to get things working.

1. Files did indeed need to have extensions.
2. The server was not
   correctly configured. It need to provide a progressive download
   response by responding with a range of headers.

By updating our backend to provide this response AND append the correct extension to the video files, we are now streaming to `AVPlayer` as expected. Thank you to everyone who offered tips!

Comment: Can u share the code to play a video with .mp4 format from url. That would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

`AVURLAsset` is require a file extension to work. unfortunately there are already some radars open for the same issue from iOS 5 but it seems even it is not updated on iOS 10.

**Radar links:**

[AVURLAsset should not require a file extension to work](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1516408)

[AVURLAsset should not require a file extension to work](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1516408)

**WorkAround /  Hack:**

Cycle through the playable MIME types and create a symbolic links to the actual file with the extension and check if they are playable.

Note:

- Symbolic Link will be deleted when the app entered into background
- To Create symbolic link check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501670/how-to-play-movie-files-with-no-file-extension-on-ios-with-mpmovieplayercontroll) SO answers

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, I don't believe the symlink option will work for me, as the file in question is remote (HTTPS). As far as I know (and have tested), `NSFileManager` throws an error when you try to symlink from `file://` to `https://`.